# Why don't my vtt subtittles show up on my html5 video?

Tags: html, video, subtitle, webvtt

I'm trying to use subtitles with my HTML5 video tag, but I can't get this to work.
I think the issue is that the video source isn't a local file. 
Does anyone know how I can get around this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style id="stndz-style"></style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" controls autoplay="" name="media">
        <source src="http://localhost:8888/" type="video/mp4">
        <track label="Dutch" kind="subtitles" srclang="nl" src="/home/ubuntu/Desktop/scripts/example.vtt" default>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my example.vtt:

```
WEBVTT

00:01.000 --> 00:04.000
Never drink liquid nitrogen.

00:05.000 --> 00:09.000
- It will perforate your stomach.
- You could die.
```

Comment: I don’t understand. You are running a web server in localhost already. What not use that the serve the vtt?

Comment: Are you sure http://localhost:8888/ is the direct link to the mp4 file? What if you try it with a local file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that cromium not letting me use local files was the issue. So my workaround is to run chromium like this:

```
chromium --allow-file-access-from-files
```